# moving from memory to register and reading it in gdb

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm

```
section .data
    price dd 49,98,29
section .text
    global  _start
_start:
    nop
; Put your experiments between the two nops...
    mov eax,price
    mov ebx,[price]
    mov ecx,[price+4]
    mov edx, [price+8]
; Put your experiments between the two nops...
    nop
```

I understand that 49,98,29 are a byte apart from. When price is referenced it will only print out 49. I must move price by 1 byte to get 98 and 2 bytes to get 29.

In gdb I can see that the register edx has the decimal 29, ecx 98 and ebx 49.
However when I examine the register with `x/3dw $edx` I get

```
Cannot access memory at address 0x1d
```

Why isn't it showing 29?

Update:

I am trying to see output of the code below

```
section .data
    price db 49,98,29
section .text
    global  _start
_start:
    nop
; Put your experiments between the two nops...
    mov eax, price          
    mov ebx,[price]
    mov ecx,[price+1]
    mov edx, [price+2]
; Put your experiments between the two nops...
    nop
```

`x/db $ebx` gives

```
0x1d6231:       Cannot access memory at address 0x1d6231
```

and

```
(gdb) p $ebx
$5 = 1925681
```

Why is it doing this?

Comment: `x` is examine memory. You want `p` to print value. `0x1d == 29`.

Comment: `x/3dw $edx` uses the value in EDX as an address.  You need `x/3dw &price` do dump the three GDB-words = x86 dwords at that symbol address.  (Without type information GDB doesn't know it's an array that should "decay" to a pointer)

Comment: The numbers are DWORDs (4 bytes) each, because you use `dd`.  That's why you use [price+4] to get the second number and [price+8] to get the third.

Comment: i thought i only had to specify a type when i am moving an immediate data to memory data?

Comment: I have been experimenting with this same problem. Why is it that  when
price db 49,98,29  can't see the numbers in the register?

Comment: You can but you don't recognize them :) The registers you use are 4 bytes in size so you load all the numbers and an extra byte from memory, which is accidentally zero. Since x86 is little endian, that means you end up with `0x001d6231` where you can see the bytes in hex. If you have bytes you should use byte sized registers or zero extend from byte to dword e.g. `movzx ebx, byte [price]`.

Comment: re: specifying a type: you *don't* have to specify a type in the asm source, that's why `mov ebx,[price]` assembles.  That's totally irrelevant to what happens in GDB.  NASM doesn't generate debug info with type information for symbols so GDB doesn't know anything about what type `price` has.  And that also has nothing to do with using a value as a pointer, like in C it would be `int tmp = price[1];`  / `return *(int*)tmp;`

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks for your explanation. I finally get it.